# Find value in an array corresponding to position of max in another one

Tags: python, numpy, data-analysis, numpy-ndarray

I have two arrays

```
c = [ [1, 2, 3],
      [3, 7, 8],
      [5, 2, 4] ]
```

and

```
u = [ [3, 7, 8],
      [1, 3, 2],
      [1, 3, 7] ]
```

I want to find the maximum of c for each row, and the corresponding value in u. That would be:

```
cMax = [3, 8, 5]
```

and

```
uMax = [8, 2, 1]
```

I have tried

```
cMax = np.nanmax(c, axis=1)
cMaxIdx = np.argmax(c, axis=1)
```

which gives

```
cMax = [3, 8, 5]
cMaxIdx = [2, 2, 0]
```

and

```
uCMax = u[:,cMaxIdx]
```

which gives

```
uCMax = [ [8, 8, 3]
          [2, 2, 1]
          [7, 7, 1] ]
```

Comment: I don't see how the duplicate is applicable here...

Comment: Sorry, check out the updated dup target.

Comment: Duplicated or not, this works:
First, `cMax = np.argmax(c, axis=1)` then `uMax = [u[i][cMax[i]] for i in range(len(u))]`

Comment: Yes, both work! Thank you so much.